# python typing: type of function with varargs or kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.8, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function like this:

```
def f(a: str, b: Union[int, float], *xs: Tuple[str, str]) -> str
    ...
```

What is its type, expressed as `typing.Callable`?

```
Callable[[str, Union[int, float], ???], str]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with an [mypy extension](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/2607):

```py
from mypy_extensions import VarArg

x: Callable[[str, Union[int, float], VarArg(Tuple[str, str])], str] = f
```

This currently isn't possible in libraryless python.

See also:

- [mypy issue #5876](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876)
- [typing issue #264](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/264)

Comment: Quick addition: at the time of writing, mypy's [extended callables](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html?highlight=varargs#extended-callable-types) have been deprecated in favor of [callback protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols)